# How to avoid MCU peripheral conflict at compile time with C macro?

Tags: c, microcontroller

When writting program for MCU, peripherals such as GPIOs, Timer channels may conflict. Is it possible to write macros in the following form to judge them when compiling or linking?

```
USED(GPIOA_15)
USED(TIMER1_CH3)
USED(GPIOA_15) // Error or warning should occur here
```

If the judgement happens at complation, it can only find conflicts in a same.c file. So it would be better if the macro works at link-time so that resource conflict of multiple source files could be inspected.

Comment: No, don't do this. Make sure to have a sound program design instead. Then this problem will not exist.

Comment: Currently, I use a single header file to manage peripherals. The confliction of peripherals is checked manually. I think a compilation warning or error when conflict would be helpful. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't use a single header file. Files are cheap, you can have as many as you like, free of charge. For each peripheral, write it's own header and the driver inside the corresponding .c file. The only thing you should share across multiple files is a register map header.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I group peripherals by features. Each feature has it's own driver and may use multiple peripherals. For example, a PWM module uses GPIO, timer, and DMA. Since other feature, such as UART communication, may also use DMA. Different features' DMA channels may conflict. However, if I put all DMA related config into a single header file, it's hard to relate DMA configs with other peripherals' config such as timer's. When a modification of PWM should be done, I have to edit two or more different header files. Any suggestion? Maybe there's some good opensource projects for reference?

Comment: The problem you describe is when you have "tight coupling" all over your project, every header including every other header in an unholy mess. To avoid that, you can pass parameters to each driver's initializing function ("constructor"). Have the initialization code of each driver memorize which resources it uses, but otherwise not care if it is using DMA channel 4 or 5. Centralize resource allocation if needed, but de-centralize the drivers themselves.

Comment: My drivers are not centralized. I have a driver.h, in which macro definitions such as #define PWM_DMA_CHANNEL DMA_CHANNEL_1 , #define COM_DMA_CHANNEL DMA_CHANNEL_2 are defined. ".c" files include the driver.h and use these macros to initialize the peripherals. The problem is in some cases, two features may use a same peripheral by mistake. For example, EEPROM module also need DMA. And by mistake, DMA channel 1 is choosed, i.e., #define EEPROM_DMA_CHANNEL DMA_CHANNEL_1 . The problem won't be found until I download it to the MCU and run it. What's worse, it may be hard to locate the problem.